# List/Output OpenSSL SSL Ciphers by usage?

Tags: ssl, redhat, openssl

I need to make a risk analysis for a given service in my Company.
For this I would need to make a comparison between SSL Cipher Suites and how often they are used to reevaluate the need for old/weak ciphers. 
Is it possible in any way to monitor/output the Cipher Suites used by OpenSSL?

The goal is that I can say for example:

- TLS 1.2 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 was used in 1234
  connections of 123456 connections
- SSLv3 SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA was used in 12 connections of 123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openssl is just the library, you'll need to add the appropriate logging to the services that use TLS to record such details.

i.e. in Apache httpd you can record the [`SSL_CIPHER`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html) environment variable that contains the cipher suite with something along the lines of:

```
CustomLog logs/ssl_ciphers_log  "%t %h \"{User-agent}i\" %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x "
```

Similarly in nginx https://serverfault.com/a/620130/37681